# Android sim card listeners

Tags: android

I want to implement a getSimstate() listener in my service class. I'm not able to do that.

I know it can be done using sim listeners in Telephony class, but I didn't find any code to implement it.

Is code available to listen to whether a SIM is ready or not?

Comment: i dont know this will help you or not so posting as comment. "take a look here: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/62.html and http://www.krvarma.com/posts/android/using-android-telephonymanager/"

Comment: You need immediate result or want t monitor state changes on the phone?

Answer (score 3):

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        tm.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
                //Code in here executed when the sim state has changed
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {

            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in Manifest File

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".SimChangedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

SimChangedReceiver class

```
public class SimChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED")) {
            Log.d("SimChangedReceiver", "--> SIM state changed <--");   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is run for dual sim also